# Firebug for debugging jQuery elements

Tags: php, jquery, debugging, firebug

I'm debugging my jQuery DataTable using Firebug. So, in the Firebub panel I see:

```
<div id="newspaper-b_length" class="dataTables_length">
<label>
Show
<select name="newspaper-b_length" size="1" aria-controls="newspaper-b">
entries
</label>
</div>
```

but I don't have this piece of code in my php files. How actually I can find these lines of code in my php files?

Comment: Why do you assume you can? I imagine these elements are generated by jQuery DataTable, so they won't be in your PHP script at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are additional wrappers created by `datatables` plugin to show entries drop down.

Most widget create wrappers/additional div to show their widget controls. Those div's are created by datatables plugin dynamically and so you will not find it in your php code.

Comment: How can I manually change the style (ie color, font) for these wrappers?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Take a look at http://datatables.net/styling/custom_classes If you couldn't find what you are looking for.. let me know what style you are trying to apply.

Comment: I'm applying media/css/demo_table_jui.css, but I cannot find newspaper-b_wrapper there.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Can you exactly tell me what color/style you are trying to apply? The styling would probably come with the default css provided by datatable.css or it may use jquery.[..].css. You can always override it in your application css.

Comment: Oh, I found dataTables_wrapper. My mistake was that I was searching for DIV id rather than DIV class in the style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

"Firebug's HTML tab shows you what the HTML looks like right now." as you can see [here](http://getfirebug.com/html).
Probably it's being generated by other code php, js or html.